# How to remove matches between unioned tables with joined tables

Tags: mysql, union, matching, metabase

I have 2 Tables

emails and fields

emails is just a list of emails and their unique identifiers and fields is in fifth normal form (i think) with a column of values(that ID data in the second column),a data column, and ids that link to the uuids in the first table.

For example:

Table 1:

```
ID    EMAIL    
--    -----  
1a2  Test@Test   
2a3   email@email|
3a4   add@add
```

Table 2:

```
value     Data        ID 
-----    ------       ---
 1       123 Main     1a2
 2      John Smith    1a2
 3         US         1a2  
 4     555-555-5555   1a2
```

In this case, table 2 only shows the data for "1a2" because they were the only one to fill them out.

So I'm trying to make a table, that couples email to the corresponding country codes AND also provides the emails that haven't registered country codes as a Null value

I've tried using UNION to display all the emails from Table 1 on Table 2 after joining table 1 and 2 on ID and then using where for the value but that shows all the emails that have the proper country code and then duplicates them in the UNIONed portion as well.

This is an example of what I'm getting:

```
EMAIL        COUNTRY CODE
-----        ------------
test@test        US
test@test        NULL
email@email      NULL
add@add          NULL
```

You'll notice that test@test is duplicated due to the union not having the proper filter

My code looks like:

```
select
    e.email as "Email",
    f.value as "Country Code"
from
    email e
join
    fields f
    ON e.id = f.id
where
    f.value = '3'
    [[and f.data like concat({{CountryCode}},'%')]]   
    -- curly brackets are for user entered variables
```

Anyways, all said and done. I'm looking for a table that appears something like this with No Duplicates

```
EMAIL        COUNTRY CODE
-----        ------------
test@test        US
email@email      NULL
add@add          NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel pretty silly after posting this, but I found the solution and am going to post it in case someone else bumps into the issue.

```
left join
    fields f
    ON e.id = f.id
where
    f.value = '3' OR f.value is null
    [[and f.data like concat({{CountryCode}},'%')]]
```

I just needed to add an "OR" for null values. Sorry if I wasted anyone's time, I was clearly overcomplicating things and managed to achieve what I was trying to do without a union at all.

Comment: This query will not work properly if the email has records for some fields but not for the '3' field.  [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4a82f268888d0175a1ca8ed6d7d002c)

Comment: Correct, however in my case, all fields are required, so I suppose that's a non-issue for me. Basically emails will either have all values, or no values. I'm trying to see all emails regardless of whether or not they have values, but also see the Country Codes attached, with no duplicates in emails that show no country codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `max()` aggregation and group by -

```
select
    e.email as "Email",
    max(f.value) as "Country Code"
from
    email e
left join
    fields f
    ON e.id = f.id
where
    f.value = '3'
    [[and f.data like concat({{CountryCode}},'%')]]   
group by  e.email
```

Comment: This would filter off users which don't have a country code entry.  Consider [using this version](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=19d87e262f3638330b992610d0e33965) if you want to stick with your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing your user metadata in key value format.  One approach here is to left join the user table to a subquery which pivots to find the country:

```
SELECT
    e.EMAIL,
    f.country_code
FROM email e
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, MAX(CASE WHEN value = 3 THEN Data END) AS country_code
    FROM fields
    GROUP BY ID
) f
    ON e.ID = f.ID;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can make the field you're interested in part of your LEFT JOIN condition.

```
SELECT
    e.EMAIL,
    f.data as countryCode
FROM email e
LEFT JOIN fields f ON f.value=3 AND e.ID=f.ID
```

Users with a value for that field will return it.  Users without will simply be NULL due to it being a LEFT join.

If you want to do a condition on the fields value, then you'll need to include a check for null as well.

```
SELECT
    e.EMAIL,
    f.data as countryCode
FROM email e
LEFT JOIN fields f ON f.value=3 AND e.ID=f.ID
WHERE
    f.data IS NULL 
    OR f.data='US'
```